# Asp.NET Identity User not logging in after role assignment

Tags: asp.net, .net, identity

I have created a site with asp.net Identity logins work fine from the computer i test with. After registration the user is logged in and sent to a "message board" page that checks to see if the user has a role then either shows the message or a message stating to contact for account approval. After a role is assigned going back to a different page and coming back to the message board the original message still shows. so i log out and it processes the login as successful and redirects, but when it gets to the welcome page the user is not logged in as far as the server is concerned (i have a label on the page that displays the identity user information (it says nothing was found))  a restart of the site in iis solves the issue for a little bit. any tips on getting this fixed?

```
Public Class ApplicationSignInManager
    Inherits SignInManager(Of ApplicationUser, String)
    Public Sub New(userManager As ApplicationUserManager, authenticationManager As IAuthenticationManager)
        MyBase.New(userManager, authenticationManager)
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function CreateUserIdentityAsync(user As ApplicationUser) As Task(Of ClaimsIdentity)
        Return user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(DirectCast(UserManager, ApplicationUserManager))
    End Function

    Public Shared Function Create(options As IdentityFactoryOptions(Of ApplicationSignInManager), context As IOwinContext) As ApplicationSignInManager
        Return New ApplicationSignInManager(context.GetUserManager(Of ApplicationUserManager)(), context.Authentication)
    End Function
End Class
```

SignInManager

```
    Public Class SignInManager(Of TUser As {Class, IUser(Of TKey)}, TKey As 
    IEquatable(Of TKey))
    Implements IDisposable
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Constructor
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   userManager:
    '
    '   authenticationManager:
    Public Sub New(userManager As UserManager(Of TUser, TKey), authenticationManager As IAuthenticationManager)

    '
    ' Summary:
    '     AuthenticationType that will be used by sign in, defaults to DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie
    Public Property AuthenticationType As String
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Used to operate on users
    Public Property UserManager As UserManager(Of TUser, TKey)
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Used to sign in identities
    Public Property AuthenticationManager As IAuthenticationManager

    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Dispose
    Public Sub Dispose()
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     If disposing, calls dispose on the Context. Always nulls out the Context
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   disposing:
    Protected Overridable Sub Dispose(disposing As Boolean)

    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Called to generate the ClaimsIdentity for the user, override to add additional
    '     claims before SignIn
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   user:
    Public Overridable Function CreateUserIdentityAsync(user As TUser) As Task(Of ClaimsIdentity)
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Convert a TKey userId to a string, by default this just calls ToString()
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   id:
    Public Overridable Function ConvertIdToString(id As TKey) As String
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Convert a string id to the proper TKey using Convert.ChangeType
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   id:
    Public Overridable Function ConvertIdFromString(id As String) As TKey
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Creates a user identity and then signs the identity using the AuthenticationManager
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   user:
    '
    '   isPersistent:
    '
    '   rememberBrowser:
    <AsyncStateMachineAttribute(GetType(SignInManager(Of Object, Object).<SignInAsync>d__2))> <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Overridable Function SignInAsync(user As TUser, isPersistent As Boolean, rememberBrowser As Boolean) As Task
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Send a two factor code to a user
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   provider:
    <AsyncStateMachineAttribute(GetType(SignInManager(Of Object, Object).<SendTwoFactorCodeAsync>d__6))> <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Overridable Function SendTwoFactorCodeAsync(provider As String) As Task(Of Boolean)
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Get the user id that has been verified already or null.
    <AsyncStateMachineAttribute(GetType(SignInManager(Of Object, Object).<GetVerifiedUserIdAsync>d__d))> <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Function GetVerifiedUserIdAsync() As Task(Of TKey)
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Has the user been verified (ie either via password or external login)
    <AsyncStateMachineAttribute(GetType(SignInManager(Of Object, Object).<HasBeenVerifiedAsync>d__11))> <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Function HasBeenVerifiedAsync() As Task(Of Boolean)
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Two factor verification step
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   provider:
    '
    '   code:
    '
    '   isPersistent:
    '
    '   rememberBrowser:
    <AsyncStateMachineAttribute(GetType(SignInManager(Of Object, Object).<TwoFactorSignInAsync>d__14))> <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Overridable Function TwoFactorSignInAsync(provider As String, code As String, isPersistent As Boolean, rememberBrowser As Boolean) As Task(Of SignInStatus)
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Sign the user in using an associated external login
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   loginInfo:
    '
    '   isPersistent:
    <AsyncStateMachineAttribute(GetType(SignInManager(Of Object, Object).<ExternalSignInAsync>d__1d))> <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Function ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo As ExternalLoginInfo, isPersistent As Boolean) As Task(Of SignInStatus)
    '
    ' Summary:
    '     Sign in the user in using the user name and password
    '
    ' Parameters:
    '   userName:
    '
    '   password:
    '
    '   isPersistent:
    '
    '   shouldLockout:
    <AsyncStateMachineAttribute(GetType(SignInManager(Of Object, Object).<PasswordSignInAsync>d__29))> <DebuggerStepThrough>
    Public Overridable Function PasswordSignInAsync(userName As String, password As String, isPersistent As Boolean, shouldLockout As Boolean) As Task(Of SignInStatus)
End Class
```

Startup.Auth

```
 Public Sub ConfigureAuth(app As IAppBuilder)
        'Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(AddressOf ApplicationDbContext.Create)
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationUserManager)(AddressOf ApplicationUserManager.Create)
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(Of ApplicationSignInManager)(AddressOf ApplicationSignInManager.Create)

        ' Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(New CookieAuthenticationOptions() With {
            .AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            .Provider = New CookieAuthenticationProvider() With {
                .OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity(Of ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser)(
                    validateInterval:=TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                    regenerateIdentity:=Function(manager, user) user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))},
            .LoginPath = New PathString("/Account/Login")})
        ' Use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie)

        ' Enables the application to temporarily store user information when they are verifying the second factor in the two-factor authentication process.
        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))

        ' Enables the application to remember the second login verification factor such as phone or email.
        ' Once you check this option, your second step of verification during the login process will be remembered on the device where you logged in from.
        ' This is similar to the RememberMe option when you log in.
        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie)

        ' Uncomment the following lines to enable logging in with third party login providers
        'app.UseMicrosoftAccountAuthentication(
        '    clientId:= "",
        '    clientSecret:= "")

        'app.UseTwitterAuthentication(
        '   consumerKey:= "",
        '   consumerSecret:= "")

        'app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        '   appId:= "",
        '   appSecret:= "")

        'app.UseGoogleAuthentication(New GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions() With {
        '   .ClientId = "",
        '   .ClientSecret = ""})
    End Sub
```

Comment: Please post your code so that someone can find the issue. Also, use community guidelines before you post question so that people do not down vote your question.

Comment: No way to answer this w/o seeing some code.

Comment: i dont even know where to begin looking for a solution to the issue. do you want code from Web.config? Startup.Auth?

Comment: Let's first debug a little...  Try logging in as you described, then log out and try to log back in.  Do this without the steps involving role assignment.

Comment: The issue is almost certainly in your AccountController in the login method.  Look for anything in that method which does something with roles.

Comment: @nurdyguy I have posted ApplicationSignInManager Class inside IdentityConfig.vb i have browsed MetaData of SignInManager also and didn't find anything even mentioning roles.

Comment: Can you post `SignInManager` also? (Unless it is just part of the Identity framework, not sure since I'm not familiar with the vb version.)

Comment: Also, post the startup.Auth or any where else you registered the package.

Comment: @nurdyguy i have tried it on a fresh iis installation to see if it was something it didn't like from the existing configuration (2 other sites on the server) and still no luck.